# Как осуществить двойной переворот данных в SQL запросе?

Tags: android, sql

Есть `SQL` в которой, предположим, 500 строк. я с помощью запроса

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(MESSAGES_TABLE, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder, howManyShow);
```

, где `selection`, `selectionArgs` - условия выборки (например "`channel = ?`", "67822" - выводить сообщения только с полем `channel = 67822`)
`sortOrder`, `howManyShow` - порядок выборки (например " `_id DESC`" , " 30" -выбирать сообщения с конца базы данных и передавать в курсор только 30)

Соответственно в курсоре получаем 30 сообщений, начиная  с 500-го . Но мне нужно заполнять этим курсором мой `ListFragment` в обратном порядке, так чтобы "500-ое" сообщение было в низу `List`. Есть ли вариант как изменить запрос что бы эти же 30 сообщений выводились в `cursor` в обратном порядке("500-ое" сообщение последним").

Количество строк в базе не статично. Так же не подойдет метод отправки 2ух запросов потому что курсор тогда не будет правильно обновляться.

`ListFragment` заполняется собственным адаптером наследованным от `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Если нельзя изменить запрос под мои пожелания, может есть способы изменить порядок заполнения `List` с помощью методов `adapter`'a . Поиск в гугле говорит что надо менять запрос, но как его грамотно поменять не соображу.

Answer (score 1):

Идеальным решением будет выборка всего лишь одним запросом **order by id desc limit 30** c последующим помещением данных в массив.
Потом по условиях уже отображаешь массив данных в прямом или обратном порядке, если новые сверху - массив не трогаешь, если внизу, просто **реверсишь** массив и выводишь.
типа:

```
if (new_msg on top)
 {
 так и показывать
 }
 else
 {
 перевернуть массив и показывать
 }
```

p.s. **программирую на рнр** (ищи аналог рнр функции array_reverse() для андроид)

p.p.s **sc2tv)**